# Oracle returning incorrect result due to numeric data type limitations?

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run the following query Oracle returns 0.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999.

```
select 1/3 * 3 from dual;
```

However when I execute the following Oracle returns 1.0:

```
select 1/to_float(3) * 3 from dual;
```

Why the difference?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: My understanding is that both queries are using floating point numbers, so why the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Use decimal numbers instead of floating point. If those are constants you can cast to decimal, if they are fields in a table, declare the fields as decimal.

Comment: executing the following still returns the incorrect answer:  select cast(1 as decimal)/cast(3 as decimal) * cast(3  as decimal)from dual;